# Почему программа не отвечает, когда копирую большой объём файлов?

Tags: c++, qt, файлы

Программа перестаёт реагировать, после того как я начинаю копировать файлы и нажимаю на неё хоть один раз. Как избежать этого?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мой код:

```
void MainWindow::SaveFiles()
{
    if (!ComboBoxLog->currentData().isNull()) {
        SaveFilesButton->setDisabled(true);
        Progress->show();
        Progress->setMinimum(0);
        Progress->setMaximum(model->rowCount()-1);
        Login conn;
        conn.connOpen();
        QSqlQuery* queryAddNote = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);

        QString newDir = "";

        for (int i=1;i<model->rowCount();i++) {
            newDir = QString(QDir::currentPath()+"/"+ComboBoxLog->currentText()+"_%1"+"/"+model->index(i,2).data().toString()).arg(QString(QDate::currentDate().toString()).replace(" ","_"));
            if (QDir(newDir).exists() == false) {
                QDir().mkpath(newDir);
            }
            if (model->index(i,0).data(Qt::DisplayRole).toBool()==true) {

                    QFile::copy(model->index(i,1).data().toString(),newDir+"/"+QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName());
                    QString sqlQueryAddNote = QString("INSERT INTO data (data,path_to_data,id_log,date_add_log) VALUES ('%1','%2','%3','%4')")
                            .arg(QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName())
                            .arg(newDir+"/"+QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName())
                            .arg(ComboBoxLog->currentData().toString())
                            .arg(QDate::currentDate().toString());
                    queryAddNote->prepare(sqlQueryAddNote);
                    qDebug()<<queryAddNote->lastError();
                    queryAddNote->exec();

                Progress->setValue(i);
            } else {

            }
        }
        conn.connClose();
        Progress->hide();
        model->clear();
        SaveFilesButton->setDisabled(false);
        TableDisk->setModel(nullptr);        
        MainWindow::TableLogBuilding();
        MainTab->setCurrentIndex(1);

    } else {
        msgBox.setText("Выберите журнал в ComboBox! Обязательное поле.");
        msgBox.exec();
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Копируйте в отдельном потоке.

Comment: @Alexander Semikashev Как копировать в отдельном потоке? Можно привести пример пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы полностью загружаете поток самой формы, и поэтому ее элементы не отвечают: уже идет сохранение файлов. По сути, строение такого приложение весьма примитивно, и в одно и то же время вы можете выполнять лишь один процесс. Поэтому используйте такую вещь, как `QThread`: он предназначен для создания дополнительных потоков, которые не будут мешать работе формы.

PS. На [Хабре](https://habr.com/post/150274/) пишут, что документация в `Qt` по данному элементу неправильная. Но все равно посмотрите [тут](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects/ru) и [тут](https://evileg.com/ru/post/151/).

Comment: "Неправильная" это громко сказано, но best practice реально не в переопределении метода `run`

Comment: А можно пример увидеть..... у меня вылетает, когда я пишу свой QThread класс . Я не совсем понимаю как это использовать?